# Any other way to integrade paypal with IPN?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a script which issues a token to user when they login and for one session this token remains the same, the token also remains in the url end even if they change the page (within website). 
Now I want to integrate paypal but when the paypal IPN returns values, it remove the token from URL and page does not open.

Is there any solution for that or is there any other say to integrate paypal without using IPN?

Comment: Use cookie based sessions. I didnt know anyone used url based sessions anymore

Answer (score 0):

Include the token in the CUSTOM parameter of your standard PayPal buttons or API requests.  It will then come back in the CUSTOM parameter within the IPN data so you can utilize it accordingly.